# Grey window in Texmaker when trying to save a file

Tags: windows-7, texmaker

I use Texmaker 4.1.1 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. When I tried to save a file, I get a grey screen:

[image]

[image]

I have the same issue when I try to open a file. The issue disappeared after restarting the program. I never had have this issue in other programs. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: ask this the support of the tool.